# jQuery selector for all inputs checked or other type than radio

Tags: jquery

I'm totally lost about how to do the following:
- select all checked radio AND all other inputs of different type than radio which are inside one div

selecting all input should be `$(':input')`
selecting checked radio should be `$( "input[type=radio]:checked")`
and of course inside the div `$('#mydiv')`

`$('#mydiv :input')` matches 2 conditions: all inputs inside the div. I can of course test the type property after, but wondering if I could do it in one only selector ?

Comment: `$('#mydiv :input[type=radio]:checked')` ?

Comment: nope, I want to select the checked radio, AND all inputs with a type different than radio

Comment: `$('#mydiv :input[type=radio]:checked, #mydiv :input:not([type=radio])')`

Comment: yes exactly! Thanks a lot

Comment: @tymeJV, you may post it as an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

If you have 2 selectors, for example:

```
$("div#id")
```

and

```
$("p.class")
```

you can combine them and use them together like this:

```
$("div#id, p.class")
```

So, in your case, you should use:

```
$("#mydiv :input[type=radio]:checked, #mydiv :input:not([type=radio])")
```